# custom dialog box validation on click of a button

Tags: angular

I am using a dialog box that has a search box and two dropdowns. I have a "cancel" and a "confirm" `md-button` buttons. I want to validate the dialog box on click of confirm. The dialog box HTML has `md-dialog-content` tag. The whole HTML is inside that tag.

**Dialog box HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div md-dialog-content>
                <h4>Find your IFSC Code</h4>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" id="keyword" class="form-control"
                           name="bankname" [(ngModel)]="query" (keyup)="filter()"
                           (change)="bankChanged($event)" placeholder="BANK" />
                </div>
                <div class="filter-select" *ngIf="filteredList.length > 0">
                    <ul *ngFor="let item of filteredList" class="filter-select-list">
                        <li class="artist-name">
                            <a (click)="select(item)">{{item}}</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="sel2"></label>
                    <select class="form-control selectpicker" id="sel2" name ="city"
                            [(ngModel)]="city" (change)="cityChanged($event)">
                        <option hidden="true" value="">Select City</option>
                        <option *ngFor="let city of cities">{{city}}</option>
                    </select>
                    <label for="sel3"></label>
                    <select class="form-control selectpicker" id="sel3"
                            name ="branch" [(ngModel)]="branch"
                            (change)="branchChanged($event.target.selectedIndex -1)">
                        <option data-hidden="true" value="">Select Branch</option>
                        <option *ngFor="let branch of branches | keys">{{branch}}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div md-dialog-actions>
                    <button md-button (click)="onNoClick()" tabindex="-1">
                        Cancel
                    </button>
                    <button md-button [md-dialog-close] ="this.modaldetails" tabindex="2">
                        Confirm
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, Input, Output, EventEmitter, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MdDialog, MdDialogRef, MD_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';
import { Select2OptionData } from 'ng2-select2';
import { PaymentService } from '../../sharedService/payment.service';
import { IFSCService } from './ifscModal.service';
import { FormControl, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
// import { SearchService } from '../../sharedService/search.service';
import { KeysPipe } from '../../second/keys.pipe';


//import { ModalService } from './modal/modal.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  host: {
    '(document:click)': 'handleClick($event)',
  },
  templateUrl: './ifscModal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ifscModal.component.css'],

})
export class IFSCModalComponent {
  public query = '';
  public filteredList = [];
  public elementRef;

  value;
  str1;
  str2;
  banksArr;
  dataArr;
  bank;
  city = [];
  cities = [];
  banks = [];
  branch = [];
  branches = [];
  fields : boolean;
  ifsc: String;
  ifsccode: String;
  getIFSCCode = {};
  // modaldetails: {};
  errBlock : boolean;
  errMsg : string; 

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<IFSCModalComponent>,
    @Inject(MD_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any, public paymentservice: PaymentService,
    public ifscModalservice: IFSCService, myElement: ElementRef) {


    this.elementRef = myElement;
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.ifscModalservice.getBankList().subscribe(
      (banks_res) => {
        this.banks = banks_res["bankList"];
      },
      (error) => console.log("error : " + error),
      () => console.log('Complete getting Bank List')
    );

    console.log(this.banks);
    this.fields = false;
    this. errBlock = false;




  }


  filter() {
    console.log("query:" + this.query);
    if (this.query !== "") {
      this.filteredList = this.banks.filter(function (el) {
        return el.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.query.toLowerCase()) > -1;
      }.bind(this));

      if (this.filteredList.length == 0) {
        this.filteredList = ["No Results Found!!"];
      }
    }
    else {
      this.filteredList = this.banks;
    }
  }

  select(item) {

    this.query = item.toString();


    // console.log(this.modaldetails);
    this.filteredList = [];
  }

  handleClick(event) {
    var clickedComponent = event.target;
    var inside = false;
    do {
      if (clickedComponent === this.elementRef.nativeElement) {
        inside = true;
      }
      clickedComponent = clickedComponent.parentNode;
    } while (clickedComponent);
    if (!inside) {
      this.filteredList = [];
    }
  }
  bankChanged(val: any) {
    let obj = this.banks;
    console.log(obj, val);
    if (obj.length !== 0) {
      this.ifscModalservice.getCityList().subscribe(
        (cities_res) => {
          this.cities = cities_res["cityList"];
        },
        (error) => console.log("error : " + error),
        () => console.log('Complete getting city List')
      );


    }

  }
  cityChanged(val: any) {
    let obj = this.city;
    console.log(obj, val);

    this.ifscModalservice.getBranchList().subscribe(
      (branches_res) => {
        this.branches = branches_res["branchList"];
        //this.ifsc = this.branches;
      },
      (error) => console.log("error : " + error),
      () => console.log('Complete getting branch List')
    );
  }


  branchChanged(val: any) {
    let obj = this.branch;
    console.log(obj, val);

    //getIFSC() {
    for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(this.branches).length; i++) {
      let j = val
      this.ifsccode = this.branches[Object.keys(this.branches)[j]];

    }
    console.log(this.ifsccode);
    //}

    // this.modaldetails = {
    //   "bank": this.query,
    //   "ifscCode": this.ifsccode

    // }
    this.Confirm(); 


    console.log("bank "+this.query.length);
    console.log("city "+this.city.length);
    console.log("branch "+this.branch.length);
    console.log("ifsc "+this.ifsccode.length);
  }

  Confirm () {

    if(this.query.length>0 && this.city.length>0 && this.branch.length>0)
    {
      this.ifscModalservice.saveDetails(this.query, this.city, this.branch, this.ifsccode);
      this.errBlock = false;
    } else {
      this.errBlock = true;
      this.errMsg = "Fill out all the fields to confirm."
      console.log("button called");
    }
  }

  onNoClick() {
    //console.log(this.modaldetails);
    this.dialogRef.close();
    return this.ifscModalservice.returnDetails();
    // return this.modaldetails;
  }
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qyrmve?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

You can set a click event on `confirm` button and then can write a function to validate and return true or false as per your condition.

You html button

```
<button md-button (click)="validate()" [md-dialog-close] ="modaldetails" tabindex="2">Confirm </button>
```

And in your component you need to add the validate function to validate.

```
validate() {
  // all your validation should goes here
  this. 
}
```

this is the simplest way to manually validate. If you want you can also use `ReactiveForm`, etc

Comment: when i am clicking on it ,the function itself is not getting called

Comment: it should work as its a simple button and ng-button directive used on top of it. i dont see anything that will block click event.

Comment: i just need to check whether all the fields must not be empty and on the basis of that i have to restrict dialog box from closing when i click confirm.

Comment: Can you help me on that?

Comment: it should work, can you show me your typescript file

Comment: added.Please look.

Comment: you have confirm method but you are not calling it from html. so change your html button for confirm and add `(click)="Confirm ()"` there

Comment: i am calling it .Sorry didn't add that in the code when i was submitting the question.Its calling the function but no validation is happening .Could you help me on that?

Comment: another found in your html is `[md-dialog-close] ="this.modaldetails"`. and you dont have to mention this in html, so it will be ` [md-dialog-close] ="modaldetails"`

Comment: I dont see any other error. what error you are getting in your browser developer tool

Comment: i am not getting any error.When I am not filling any details in the dialog box and click confirm it's getting closed .It should not .My requirement is to validate the dialog box.All the three fields should be filled then only confirm should close the dialog along with sending the ifsc code and bank name

Comment: I thin `[md-dialog-close] ="this.modaldetails"` closing your form. try to find a logic around it to not close the button

Comment: I am new to angular 2.Could you help  me on that?

Comment: i have added stackblitz url as well

Comment: Please help me on this.

Comment: Can some one help me on this issue?